# Best strategy in dynamic allocation in C for strcut with many pointers

Tags: c, malloc

I wonder what is the best strategy for alloc memory for a struct with many pointers within.

Like this:

```
struct Test{
    long unsigned int size;
    double *A;
    int *B;
    double *C;
};
```

Then I could use many allocations, like this:

```
struct Test *alloc_test(long unsigned int size){
    struct Test *ans = (struct Test*)malloc(sizeof(struct Test));
    if(ans == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    ans->size = size;
    ans->A = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    if(ans->A == NULL){
        free(ans);
        return NULL;
    }
    ans->B = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    if(ans->B == NULL){
        free(ans->A);
        free(ans);
        return NULL;
    }
    ans->C = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    if(ans->C == NULL){
        free(ans->A);
        free(ans->B);
        free(ans);
        return NULL;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Or I could usi a single allocation, like this:

```
struct Test *alloc_test(long unsigned int size){
    long unsigned int mem_size = sizeof(struct Test) + sizeof(double)*2*size + sizeof(int)*size;
    struct Test *ans = (struct Test*)malloc(mem_size);
    if(ans == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    ans->size = size;
    ans->A = ans + sizeof(struct Test);
    ans->B = ans->A + sizeof(double)*size;
    ans->C = ans->B + sizeof(int)*size;
    return ans;
}
```

This is possible in that sittuation because this object shouldn't be realloced. In this case, does anyone knows the advantage of each one?

Comment: `ans->size = size;
    ans->A = ans + sizeof(struct Test);
    ans->B = ans->A + sizeof(double)*size;
    ans->C = ans->B + sizeof(int)*size;` is the wrong pointer math.  So advise against this approach.

Comment: The 2nd approach's pointer math is wrong.  Would need to use something like `ans->A = (void*) (ans + 1);  ans->B = (void*) (ans->A + size);  ans->C = (void *) (ans->B + size);`.  Yet that sets aside the important alignment issues which required further code adjustments.  Best to not use  second method until mastered pointer math and alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are possible, and which one you choose is your freedom. However, you should obey [alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) constraints (perhaps using `alignas` and `alignof` from [`<stdalign.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types) for the single allocation variant)

Read also about [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), which permits a single `malloc` in the particular case you have only *one* array member.

Notice that each call to `malloc` has its overhead (both in memory, perhaps consuming an extra word or two for internal management, and in time; a typical `malloc` takes less than a microsecond on my desktop).

For long-lasting programs e.g. servers you might also care about [fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)) (not an issue for most short lived applications)

The second approach (single `malloc`) might be slightly more [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) friendly. Most often, you won't care.

BTW (as commented by [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux))

> ```
>  ans->A = ans + sizeof(struct Test);
> ```

is wrong, because pointer arithmetic happens in units of the pointed type. You may want

```
   ans->A = ((char*)ans)+sizeof(struct Test);
```

and actually you should compute `mem_size` more carefully (using also `alignof` in it, or supposing that `alignof(long unsigned int) >= alignof(double)` and so on) then prefer

```
   char* ad = malloc(mem_size);
   if (!ad) return NULL;
   ans = ad;
   ans->A = ad + sizeof(struct Test);
```

The exact computation of `mem_size` (which needs some conditional and using `alignof`) and the real code is left as an exercise (I'm too lame to explain it here).

Comment: I didn't seem this concept of alignment before. So, the best practice is really the first one. tks

Comment: What do "I don't seem this concept" mean?

Comment: Means I wrote wrong. "I had never seen the concept..."

Comment: But you need to care about alignment as soon as a pointer is computed. `malloc` is guaranteed to give a well aligned pointer. If you implemented `malloc` you'll need to provide that guarantee. BTW many `malloc` are free software

Comment: OP's 2nd method pointer math is faulty as well as having alignment issues.

Comment: Which I explained in my second sentence

Comment: Agree 2nd sentence is about important alignment.  Setting that aside, OP's `ans->A = ans + sizeof(struct Test);` is un-reported wrong pointer math.  OP likely wanted `ans->A = (void*) (ans + 1);`

Answer (score 3):

In Plan A, you get memory fencing, architecture-specific memory alignment, ability to realloc. Of course one could refactor this a little bit so that error handling is not scattered all over - but that's a matter of personal style.

In Plan B, you lose all that automatic stuff - you will have to take care of it. Then it might get very difficult to read.

Depending on your allocator, you might have an easier time finding multiple smaller chunks of memory than one mega chunk. So, strategy-wise, you have to make your own decision - if you have your own allocator.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you how to handle the error in a much cleaner way for your first case:

```
struct Test *alloc_test(long unsigned int size)
{
    struct Test *ans = malloc(sizeof(struct Test));
    if(ans == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    ans->size = size;
    ans->A = malloc(sizeof(ans->A) * size);
    ans->B = malloc(sizeof(ans->B) * size);
    ans->C = malloc(sizeof(ans->C) * size);

    if(ans->A == NULL || ans->B == NULL || ans->C == NULL)
    {
        free(ans->A);
        free(ans->B);
        free(ans->C);
        free(ans);
        return NULL;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: For clearer code, could use `ans->A = malloc(sizeof *(ans->A) * size);`, etc.  No need for cast and size to the referenced data.

Comment: @chux you are right. Ty. Edited

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to use multiple calls to `malloc()` or deal with alignment at all.

If all the dynamically-allocated arrays will always have the same number of elements, use a `struct` that contains the actual *values*, and create an array of the `struct`:

```
typedef struct data
{
    double A;
    double B;
    int C;
};
```

Allocation:

```
struct data *dataPtr = malloc( size * sizeof( *dataPtr ) );
```

Deallocation:

```
free( dataPtr );
```

Simple and easily understandable.

If you need to carry the size around with the data, use a `struct` with a flexible array of `struct data`:

```
typedef struct test
{
    unsigned long size;
    struct data[];
}
```

Allocation:

```
struct test *testPtr = malloc( sizeof( *testPtr ) + size * sizeof( testPtr->data ) );
testPtr ->size = size;
```

Deallocation:

```
free( testPtr );
```